# Optimal topology for high-power small factor SMPS

Tags: power, switch-mode-power-supply, topology

I'm trying to design a relatively small and compact SMPS for an output rating between 200/300 W (400 V in and 20 V out). The AC input from mains is rectified and filtered and fed to a PFC boost stage where the output is around 400VDC. Then the next stage would be a isolated topology to step down the voltage.

What would be the optimal isolated topology to achieve the smallest form factor given the power rating?

Comment: Is the input DC?

Comment: Input would be AC rectified and boosted (+PFC)to 400V

Comment: Can you edit the question to include that information? The fact that you need to rectify AC to DC with PFC may have an impact on the topology.

Comment: Check out the LLC resonant converter topology.